# Get Second To Last Element For SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I have a sorted dictionary that looks like such:

```
SortedDictionary<DateTime, string> mySortedDictionary = GetDataSource();
```

To get the last element, I noticed that I am able to do this:

```
DateTime last = Convert.ToDateTime(mySortedDictionary.Keys.Last());
```

Is there any way to get the second-to-last item? The way that I am currently thinking of involves getting the last item and then calculating what the second to last item would be. My DateTime keys all have a set pattern, however, it is not guaranteed that I know them exactly.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, the method you are currently using to get the last item is starting at the beginning and getting every single item until it reaches the end.

Comment: @Servy I don't understand what you mean. So it iterates through the collectionary, but how does that help me get the second to last element since it returns the last one?

Comment: It doesn't.  I'm just saying, that method you're using is not efficient.  It's iterating the entire sequence to get there.  If you thought that because it's sorted it was getting the item quickly, you would be wrong.

Comment: Do you need the dictionary to be in Ascending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dictionary.Keys.Reverse().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
```

This will take `O(n)` time, but I as far as I can tell there seems to be no fast solution.

Comment: It definitely does take O(N). Everything else would be magic.

Comment: LINQ contains some optimizations - if an object implements an interface like `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>` or is an array, LINQ will take advantage of this if it helps speeding up operations. But I just checked it, `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` does not implement any useful interfaces.

Comment: of course it's possible but the optimization would need to flow through 2-3 unrelated operators. Unlikely.

Comment: If the key collection would implement `IList<T>` it would work - `FirstOrDefault()` would request one item from `Skip(1)`, `Skip(1)` would request two items from `Reverse()`, and `Reverse()` would just use the indexer to obtain the two last items from `Keys` turning all together into `O(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Using linq you can skip all items until the second to last and take the first one (but first check if the dictionary has at least 2 elements):

```
var secondToLast = mySortedDictionary.Skip(mySortedDictionary.Count - 2).First();
```

Comment: This may have some problems - it will throw an exception if the dictionary is empty and return the last item if there is only a single item in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get the second to last item.  Note that it needs to iterate the *entire* sequence of keys to get it, so it will not be efficient.  Also note that I've mostly ignored the cases of a 0 or 1 item sequence; you can check for it and throw, or do something else, if you don't want to be given the default value.

```
public static T SecondToLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    T previous = default(T);
    T current = default(T);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = item;
    }

    return previous;
}
```

To use it:

```
DateTime secondToLast = mySortedDictionary.Keys.SecondToLast();
```

Comment: I like this approach very much. It's a solidly implemented reusable helper function. Need to solve the edge cases on 0-1 items though.

Comment: @usr Well, this is likely one appropriate solution; it's effectively `SecondToLastOrDefault`.  I didn't feel like making 3 different overloads for handling the alternate behaviors of throwing an exception or using a default value passed as a parameter as that seemed... excessive, given the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you store the keys reversed? In that case you can just use `mySortedDictionary.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()`.

You can reverse the key sort order by specifying a (simple) custom `IComparer` in the constructor.